# Sqlplus - Export and spool result

Tags: sql, oracle, export, sqlplus

I am using shell script to execute an export in sqlplus

Spool:

```
SET echo off
SET linesize 32767
SET LONG 1000
SET LONGCHUNKSIZE 1000
SET wrap off
SET heading off
SET colsep ';'
SET pagesize 0
SET feed off
SET termout off
SET trimspool off

SELECT
AUTO_SEQ.nextval as ROW_ID,
..
..
```

And the result:

```
  29419987;FOR_IMPORT;1000         ;KR 19 F 65 73                                                                                                                                                                       ;KR 19 F 65 73, 47001, 47000                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ;SANTA MARTA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ;Cargado por EIM en 03-MAY-17         ;KR 19 F 65 73, 47001, 47000                                                                                             ;KR 19 F 65 73, 47001, 47000                                                                                             ;KR 19 F 65 73, 47001, 47000                                                                                             ;MAGDALENA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ;          ;COLOMBIA;                                                            ;                                                            ;                                                                                          ;   ;         ;Y;N;Y
```

The result has many blanks before and/or after the data, so my question is how can I remove them ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just grab yourself the current version of SQL Plus, and you'll be good to go

```
SQL> set markup csv on
SQL> select * from scott.emp;

"EMPNO","ENAME","JOB","MGR","HIREDATE","SAL","COMM","DEPTNO"
7369,"SMITH","CLERK",7902,"17-DEC-80",800,,20
7499,"ALLEN","SALESMAN",7698,"20-FEB-81",1600,300,30
7521,"WARD","SALESMAN",7698,"22-FEB-81",1250,500,30
7566,"JONES","MANAGER",7839,"02-APR-81",2975,,20
7654,"MARTIN","SALESMAN",7698,"28-SEP-81",1250,1400,30
7698,"BLAKE","MANAGER",7839,"01-MAY-81",2850,,30
7782,"CLARK","MANAGER",7839,"09-JUN-81",2450,,10
7788,"SCOTT","ANALYST",7566,"09-DEC-82",3000,,20
7839,"KING","PRESIDENT",,"17-NOV-81",5000,,10
7844,"TURNER","SALESMAN",7698,"08-SEP-81",1500,,30
7876,"ADAMS","CLERK",7788,"12-JAN-83",1100,,20
7900,"JAMES","CLERK",7698,"03-DEC-81",950,,30
7902,"FORD","ANALYST",7566,"03-DEC-81",3000,,20
7934,"MILLER","CLERK",7782,"23-JAN-82",1300,,10
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `colsep` doesn't stop the results being output in columns, and that means the values in each row are still padded out to the same length. I'd forget about `colsep` and instead concatenate the values together with the delimiter:

```
SELECT
  AUTO_SEQ.nextval
  ||';'|| column1
  ||';'|| column2
  ...
  ||';'|| columnN
FROM
  ...
```

That gives a single column expression, with no extra spaces added.

You *may* need to enclose string value sin double quotes if they could contain the delimiter themselves (though that depends a bit on who will consume this), and you can concatenate those in as well. You should also explicitly format dates as strings etc. if you aren't already.