# SQLPlus newbie issue

Tags: sql, oracle, automation, export, sqlplus

If i try to run this script sql file in sql developer it runs fine.

```
spool C:\Users\jpsantos\Desktop\teste.csv
set feedback off
set SQLFORMAT csv
select 1 from dual;
spool off;
```

But if I try to automate with SQLPlus, I get the following error

> SP2-0158: SET desconhecida, opþÒo "SQLFORMAT"

My SQLPlus version is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production? Is that the issue?

How can I export the file properly as csv. Is there a simple Way?

Comment: I also tried with /*csv*/, it doesn't return a error, but doesn't export the file in csv format, just the plain sql results

Comment: SQL\*Plus doesn't support either of those. If you don't want to do it manually, [try SQLcl instead](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html). It is closely related to SQL Developer and supports both forms.

Comment: Is there a simple way to open SQL developer with cmd.exe and run the script? That's all I need. I will check sqlcl, also read about it

Comment: That's what SQLcl is for *8-) But also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17390832) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43772075) for alternative approaches. Depends if you want to modify the script...

Comment: OK, thanks Alex! I will post an update after I check sqlcl, hopefully it will work